# Is there another name for a "Multi-Injective" function?

Tags: functions, reference-request

Through some research I have been doing, I came to realize that the functions I am working on are "Multi-Injective", however I can't find any literature on such functions, and I figure that I might just be using the incorrect term.

By "Multi-Injective", I'm borrowing the structure of the term from "Multilinear", so the function is injective with respect to each individual variable. For example, one could consider a "Tri-Injective" function $f:A^3 \rightarrow B$, such that

$$ f(a,b,c) = f(d,b,c) \implies a = d $$
$$ f(a,b,c) = f(a,d,c) \implies b = d $$
$$ f(a,b,c) = f(a,b,d) \implies c = d $$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @MorganRodgers I don't think it is: take $A=B=\{0,1\}$ and let $f$ be the "parity function" sending $(a,b,c)$ to $1$ iff an odd number of $a,b,$ and $c$ equal $1$. Then $f$ is non-injective but is "tri-injective."

Comment: @MorganRodgers: the product function $f(a,b,c)=abc$ is $3$-injective but not injective.

Comment: aka an injective operation as the ones left off form a tuple.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I apparently didn't fully understand this multi-injective definition at first

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What do you mean? (They certainly aren't injective in general,see my and Taladris's comments above.)

Comment: I'd probably just say "injective in each variable separately".

Comment: I mean set the left overs into a tuple, like,$$f(a,(b,c))=f(d,(b,c))\implies a=d$$